# How to convert a Java Project into a Maven Project

Tags: java, maven

I need to convert the project that has Jars into a Maven Project. If it can be done automatically it would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. Read [Maven in 5 Minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) **and** [Maven Getting Started Guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/). Or just wait and see if it happens automatically. Best of luck with your project!

Comment: Please share your [research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) and your [attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) in the form of a [MCVE](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had the problem to convert (actually, about 1800) projects to Maven.

AFAIK, there is no existing mechanism to convert lists of jars into Maven dependencies. I wrote a heuristic on my own, which looked for the checksums and names of the jars in MavenCentral and found "likely" matches, but there was still a lot of manual work involved.